# Using JOptionpane to create an object

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I want to add a Person or a firm object to an arrayList, with a type of vehicle using JOptionPane or any other option that is available. Is there anyway to do this? To use JOptionPane to call for my method, and add it to an arraylist along with a type of vehicle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JOptionPane is not meant for object creation, you'll have to create your objects before calling the JOptionPane visibility.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
So if I create an object, how can I then put the vehicle in an arraylist along with it person object or a firm object? 
Both will be created after one another.
Do i have to store the newly created vehicle object in an arraylist?

Comment: I can't really tell just like that, it all depends on your application architecture. Are your sure a JOptionPane is really what your are looking for?

Comment: I'm not really sure about that. But I have made `JPanel` and `JLabel` to create vehicles objects and person object. The problem seems to be that I want to connect these two together with my method `addVehicle(vehicle, newOwner)`